# To create clickable canvas using MSPointerEvent for IE 11

Tags: javascript, canvas, internet-explorer-11

I have been trying to make clickable canvas on IE 11.
So if you click on this canvas, it'll open URL in next window.
The problem originated after reading documentation of IE 11. The "MouseEvent" was changed to "MSPointerType". I did try to write `.InitPointerEvent` but it's still not working. Here is my non-functioning code.

```
</head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.id = "dgMobix-PopLayer";
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    canvas.width = body.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = body.clientHeight;

canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
 var t = document.createElement("a");
     t.href = "http://www.google.com";
 t.target="_blank";
var n = document.createEvent("MSPointerEvent");
n.initPointerEvent("click", true, true, window, 0,`` 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, true, 0, null,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,true);
t.dispatchEvent(n,true) ;
  this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
},false);

body.appendChild(canvas);
</script><canvas id="dgMobix-PopLayer" width="1366" height="646"></canvas>


</body></html>
```

before anyone mentions the .addEventListener problem, according to IE11 documentation they have removed .attachEvent (this only works on IE10 or below), now they have adopted the W3C method.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Please fix your message, it's hard to understand your question.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience. i did try my best to tell originated problem ! Hope you'll give some direction now !

Comment: PointerEvent no longer needs a MS prefix in IE11 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441233.aspx